# Concatenation of huge number of selective files from a directory in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, cat

I have more than 50000 files in a directory such as file1.txt, file2.txt, ....., file50000.txt. I would like to concatenate of some files whose file numbers are listed in the following text file (need.txt).

```
need.txt
1
4
35
45
71
.
.
.
```

I tried with the following. Though it is working, but I look for more simpler and short way.

```
n1=1
n2=$(wc -l < need.txt)
while [ $n1 -le $n2 ]
do
f1=$(awk 'NR=="$n1" {print $1}' need.txt)
cat file$f1.txt >> out.txt
(( n1++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
sed -e 's/.*/file&.txt/' need.txt | xargs cat > out.txt
```

It uses sed to translate each line into the appropriate file name and then hands the filenames to `xargs` to hand them to `cat`.

Using awk it could be done this way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC]="file"$1".txt"; ARGC++; next} {print}' need.txt > out.txt
```

Which adds each file to the `ARGV` array of files to process and then prints every line it sees.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please suggest me if I concatenate more files of similar kind. e.g. file$1.txt and infile$1.txt

Comment: If the names all follow the same pattern and you want them all in the same output file then just add more entries to `ARGV` in the awk solution (i.e. add `ARGV[ARGC]="infile"$1".txt"; ARGC++` to the block). Doing this in `sed` would require playing with the hold space to duplicate the lines I believe.

Answer (score 3):

This might also work for you:

```
sed 's/.*/file&.txt/' < need.txt | xargs cat > out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible do it without any sed or awk command. Directly using bash built-in functions and cat (of course).

```
for i in $(cat need.txt); do cat file${i}.txt >> out.txt; done
```

And as you want, it is quite simple.